# What Version of Ubuntu should I install?

Tags: versions

I'm fairly new to Linux and I'm not sure which version of Ubuntu Linux I should install.

Comment: Depends on your hardware and personal preferences. [Here is a list of all the flavors of Ubuntu](http://askubuntu.com/questions/333795/what-are-the-system-requirements-for-each-flavor-of-ubuntu-desktop).

Comment: Also, see this question: [How do I find out which version and derivative of Ubuntu is right for my hardware in terms of minimal system requirements?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/206407/how-do-i-find-out-which-version-and-derivative-of-ubuntu-is-right-for-my-hardwar)

Answer (score 2):

If you want the latest version of Ubuntu and all latest softwares then you should use Ubuntu 13.10. However it is supported only until January 2014 and you will have to upgrade when the next version comes out.

But if you want more stability then you should use Ubuntu 12.04 LTS which will be officially supported until April 2017.

Ubuntu 14.04 LTS will be released on April 2014 and will be supported until 2019.

Answer (score 1):

I just installed Ubuntu on my main PC, this Sunday, after having tried Ubuntu out on an old laptop. I'm very satisfied with 12.04 LTS. It's a good place to start. The LTS stands for "Long Term Support," meaning it will be a bit easier to search for help articles and tutorials when you get stuck.

Answer (score 0):

welcome to askubuntu ! 
 It depends on your choices. Current development version Ubuntu 13.04 has all latest features. If you like to have stable , you can use Ubuntu 12.04.3.