# Can I install ubuntu 12.04 desktop on a laptop?

Tags: installation, versions

I have a Toshiba satellite pro Intel Core 2 Duo. Which ubuntu should I install?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Possible duplicated [What are the system requirements for each flavor of Ubuntu Desktop?](http://askubuntu.com/q/333795/169736).

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can install it on a laptop. Ubuntu does not have a separate section for laptop, its the same Desktop version. So you can grab it **[here](http://www.ubuntu.com/desktop)** accordingly.

You may have trouble booting with UEFI - so see [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI) for more details if you have trouble booting.

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu Desktop is for laptop too, so you can install Ubuntu Desktop.

Regarding which Ubuntu should you install, if you mean which Ubuntu derivative, this depends on your taste and your laptop hardware.
You can check the "Derivates list" with a description of each one here: http://www.ubuntu.com/about/about-ubuntu/derivatives

Obviously you always have to take the Desktop version because, as I said before, the Desktop version is also for laptops.