# System Requirements for 13.04

Tags: system-installation

I am having Dell studio 1458 with Intel core i5 processor @ 2.27 Ghz and 4GB ram with 320 GB Hard disk space.Weather it is enough for latest ubuntu.

Comment: or possible duplicated [What are the system requirements for each flavor of Ubuntu Desktop?](http://askubuntu.com/q/333795/169736).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is well beyond the system requirements for Ubuntu 13.04.

["A Pentium 4, 1GHz system is the minimum recommended for a desktop system."](https://help.ubuntu.com/13.04/installation-guide/i386/ch03s04.html)

["With Desktop  64 megabytes    512 megabytes   5 gigabytes"](https://help.ubuntu.com/13.04/installation-guide/i386/ch03s04.html)

There is no guarantee that the graphics chip (ATI Mobility Radeon HD 4530) won't cause issues when you install, as graphics is still a bit of a sticking point, even on the latest Ubuntu release, but you will definitely have more than enough power to run it.

Comment: Yeah, before installing, try Ubuntu on live mode to make sure everything works well.