# Is Ubuntu compatible with my laptop

Tags: system-installation, laptop

Does Ubuntu work on laptops, and if so, which download do I choose?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Possible duplicated [What are the system requirements for each flavor of Ubuntu Desktop?](http://askubuntu.com/q/333795/169736).

Comment: Short answer: yes, and use 32 or 64 bit according your laptop specs.  And see http://askubuntu.com/q/206407/176889 and the linked question.

Comment: In rare cases your laptop may fail to run Linux due to incompatible graphics card driver. Try Live ISO and run hw-probe to check devices compatibility: https://github.com/linuxhw/hw-probe

Answer (score 1):

Ubuntu runs perfectly fine on laptops. If your laptop isn't very old, you should download the Ubuntu Desktop 64 bit release, which you can get [here](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, Ubuntu works on all common laptops.

- If your laptop is less than a few years old, **choose the 64-bit version.** Only choose the 32-bit version if it's a really old computer.
- If you want a very stable computer and very good support, choose the LTS (long term support) releases. The newest is **Ubuntu 12.04 LTS.**
- If you want to have the newest version, then Ubuntu 13.04 is the one to choose. Ubuntu 13.10 will be released in a few weeks.

Answer (score 1):

Ubuntu is of course compatible with laptops. You can choose every ubuntu version best fitting would be the Desktop variant. Both 32-bit and 64-bit work.

If you don't have a diskdrive you need an usbdrive and follow the instructions link on http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop.

Whether you want 13.04 or the 12.04LTS version depends on you. Both should be completely fine.