# Which version is recommended for my system?

Tags: system-requirements

my system specifications are:
Compaq Presario model
CPU: Intel Celeron(R) CPU 2.93GHz
Speed and Memory: 2.95GHz, 632 MB of RAM
hard disc: 40 GB

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Possible duplicated [What are the system requirements for each flavor of Ubuntu Desktop?](http://askubuntu.com/q/333795/169736).

Comment: @Braiam : He ask a specific question about his system. Have you really used Ubuntu 12.04 or 13.04 under those specs ? Because I did and you must really be patient on each clic you give (even on recommended configuration). There is a difference between running and 'can be used'.

Comment: @AntoineRodriguez the question is "Which version is recommended for my system?" which can be translated to "Which version is recommended for my system specifications?" which is all covered by that questions, and if you look at the end there is Lubuntu/Xubuntu. BTW, I run Ubuntu GNOME remix with less memory than OP's and runs fine and fast. The hardware recommendation is also covered: *"[...] card with OpenGL 1.4 support (All GPUs released today by either NVidia, AMD or Intel; GPUs released by NVidia and AMD over the last 5 years; GPUs released by Intel after the GMA 950)"*

Comment: @Braiam : Maybe for Gnome Remix you did it. But using Ubuntu with just the recommended requirements is just about to see how slow unity can be. That's the difference between official system recommended requirements and real field use (just like yours with Gnome Remix or by the comment on the ubuntu answer of your question). You can't just check those requirements to be sure that's a real good option for you.

Answer (score 1):

Use 32Bit of recent [Lubuntu](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Lubuntu/GetLubuntu) or maybe [Xubuntu](http://xubuntu.org/getxubuntu/) (consume a little more ressources).

Your system does not support 64Bit.

Answer (score -2):

Try: Ubuntu 10.04, 10.10 & 11.04.

Although you could install something more lightweight like [Lubuntu](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Lubuntu/GetLubuntu).

Comment: Versions of Ubuntu before 12.04 are EOL and should not be installed.