# What are the specs needed to run Ubuntu 13.04?

Tags: 13.04, hardware, intel, ram

I am thinking of putting Ubuntu 13.04 onto some machines.

They are three years old and I can't find anywhere some hardware specs that these machines should meet.
Please let me know!

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

Specs from:

[What are the system requirements for each flavour of Ubuntu Desktop](https://askubuntu.com/questions/333795/what-are-the-system-requirements-for-each-flavor-of-ubuntu-desktop)

Minimum

```
RaringRingtail (13.04 32-bit)
    384 MB of RAM
    700 MHz processor (about Intel Celeron or better)
    5 GB of hard-drive space
    VGA capable of 1024x768 screen resolution
    Either a CD/DVD drive or a USB port for the installer media
```

Recommended

```
RaringRingtail (13.04 64-bit)
    1 GB of RAM
    Dual Core processor
    10 GB of hard-drive space or SSD (the more hard disk capacity, the better)
    Any graphics card with OpenGL 1.4 support (All GPUs released today by either NVidia, AMD or Intel; GPUs released by NVidia and AMD over the last 5 years; GPUs released by Intel after the GMA 950)
    Either a CD/DVD drive or a USB port for the installer media
    Internet access is helpful
```

With 3 year old machines I can't see there being a problem meeting the recommended spec (which IMHO is needed for reasonable desktop performance).

Cheers, Nick