# Installing Ubuntu on Dell Inspiron 6400

Tags: windows-xp, inspiron

I have a Dell Inspiron 6400 with windows XP home
and I want to know if i can install ubuntu on it. 728RAM

Comment: possible duplicated [What are the system requirements for each flavor of Ubuntu Desktop?](http://askubuntu.com/q/333795/169736).

Comment: You can always try any of the Ubuntu flavours from a live CD/DVD or USB without installing.  To test before you commit.

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't install Ubuntu unity on it. I doubt it'll make you happy. If I were you, I'd install Lubuntu. It's a lightweight distro specially made for older computers.

Comment: [Xubuntu](http://xubuntu.org/) is prettier, and his laptop can definitely handle it. That may be a better choice than Lubuntu.