# How to make compiz consume less resources?

Tags: compiz

Every time my machine is stumbling, I run a top command and the compiz process is eating a lot of CPU. How can I configure it to consume the minimum of machine resources? I don't care for fancy graphics or effects. I have an integrated intel graphic card.

Comment: See [What are the system requirements for each flavor of Ubuntu Desktop?](http://askubuntu.com/q/333795/25656) for less hungry environments.

Comment: Your machine may be underpowered, but Compiz is also buggy and sometimes crashes or gets into an unstable state. At this point you can run "compiz --replace" (from the dash, or using the Alt-F2 shortcut). That will 'reboot' Compiz without having to close any programs or log out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My computer had an integrated Intel board. I've installed a new NVida 630 card and everything is great now. If I knew that it would improve so much, I'd had installed it before.

Long are the days where we could install Linux in old machines. If you have a weak graphic card, use Lubuntu, Xubuntu or Mint. After years re-compiling Gentoo, I just wanted the most used linux on the market. Bad choice for my machine.

Answer (score 0):

Install CCSM and de-select any nonessential effects plugins

To install Compizconfig settings manager open a terminal (ctrl + alt + T) and run this command (you can paste it into the terminal with ctrl + shift + v):

```
sudo apt-get install compizconfig-settings-manager python-compizconfig compiz-fusion-plugins-extra compiz-fusion-bcop compiz-fusion-plugins-main compizconfig-backend-gconf
```

Information regarding the usage of CCSM can be found [here](http://wiki.compiz.org/CCSM)

Comment: This message looks reasonable, why it were downvoted? Which effects may I considere "nonessential"?

Comment: you can test by deselecting one plugin at a time and see if it works for you. there're many plugins out there. it is considered nonessential in the sense that it doesn't break things or your working habits.