# What ubuntu should I download for a macbook air 2011?

Tags: macbook

I found out that I need to download the 64bit. But what version should I download. 12.04 or 13.04. Thanks!

Comment: possible duplicated [What are the system requirements for each flavor of Ubuntu Desktop?](http://askubuntu.com/q/333795/169736).

Comment: This question does is not eliciting opinionated answers so far...

Answer (score 1):

Generally, you'll want to go with the newest version unless you are running a server or something and need LTS (Long Term Support). 13.04 should be fine.