# Which version is compatible with my 8 year old dell?

Tags: system-installation, hardware

My computer has 1gb of Ram, Intel(R) Pentium(R) D  2.80GHz.

Should I install Ubuntu 12.04 LTS 32bit or 64bit or Ubuntu 13.04  32bit or 64bit?

I know Ubuntu has a word processor, but am I correct in assuming that I can install MS office 2007?

Comment: related [What are the system requirements for each flavor of Ubuntu Desktop?](http://askubuntu.com/q/333795/169736).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What are the system requirements for each flavour of Ubuntu Desktop](http://askubuntu.com/questions/333795/what-are-the-system-requirements-for-each-flavour-of-ubuntu-desktop)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With specs like those I would say 12.04 32bit but you might want to try something lighter like Lubuntu or Kubuntu.

As for your second question I want to say no. You can open the documents with MS office formats using LibreOffice but I'm not sure that you can install that in Ubuntu.

Comment: +1 for your suggestion to install Lubuntu or Kubuntu. and yes He can install MS Office 2007 using Wine.

Comment: Okay thanks. I didn't know that. I don't really like doing things with Wine anyway.

Comment: I guess i better upgrade my PC before i upgrade the OS. Thank you troylatroy & thank you Saurav Kumar.