# Is it possible to have 2 os in the same pc?

Tags: installation, dual-boot, versions

I am currently using Windows 7 Ultimate and am interested in Ubuntu OS. My PC has the following specifications :

- 1 tb harddisk
- 4 gb ram
- 1 gb graphics card amd athalon
- 3 processor 64 bit

Which version of Ubuntu is OK for me?
Where can i get it from?
I am an Indian resident.

Comment: See [How do I install Ubuntu?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/6328/how-do-i-install-ubuntu)

Comment: also, possible duplicated [What are the system requirements for each flavor of Ubuntu Desktop?](http://askubuntu.com/q/333795/169736)

Answer (score 6):

Yes you can have both on the same. The installer even does the partitioning for you.

***Ubuntu Installer***
[image]

You can find all downloads here [here](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop)

There are two verisons of Ubuntu:

***Ubuntu 13.04:***

- has the latest features
- direct link 64-bit [here](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/thank-you?distro=desktop&bits=64&release=lts)
- torrent 64-bit [here](http://releases.ubuntu.com/13.04/ubuntu-13.04-desktop-amd64.iso.torrent)

***Ubuntu 12.04:***

- For extended support,
- direct link 64-bit [here](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/thank-you?release=lts&bits=64&distro=desktop&status=zeroc)
- torrent 64-bit, [here](http://releases.ubuntu.com/12.04/ubuntu-12.04.3-alternate-amd64.iso.torrent)

***Further help***

As user68186 mentioned:
If you are confused on how to further install it there is a nice guide [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/6328/how-do-i-install-ubuntu).

Comment: +1 to provide the complete description and the picture..

Answer (score 0):

Of course you can have 2 OS in the same pc. And with your pc specifications you can get the latest version Ubuntu 13.04 (cause the version 13.10 will be released the 17th October). You can download the 64bit version from the Ubuntu website for free:

http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/thank-you?release=latest&bits=64&distro=desktop&status=zeroc