# Minimum system reqirerments for Ubuntu 13.10

Tags: installation, 13.10, system-requirements

I'm new to linux and I was just wondering what the minimum system requirement for Ubuntu 13.10 were. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Even though 13.10 isn't mentioned. [This](http://askubuntu.com/questions/333795/what-are-the-system-requirements-for-each-flavor-of-ubuntu-desktop) could give you a hint.

Answer (score 1):

Latest system requirements for the "Ubuntu Desktop Edition" are

- 700 MHz processor (about Intel Celeron or better)
- 512 MiB RAM (system memory)
- 5 GB of hard-drive space
- VGA capable of 1024x768 screen resolution
- Either a CD/DVD drive or a USB port for the installer media
- (Internet access is helpful)

Source: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/SystemRequirements

Answer (score 0):

> The system requirements vary among Ubuntu products. For the main
>   Ubuntu desktop product, the official Ubuntu Documentation recommends a
>   1 GHz Pentium 4 processor with 768 megabytes of RAM and 5 gigabytes of
>   hard drive space, or better. For less powerful computers, there are
>   other Ubuntu distributions such as Lubuntu and Xubuntu.

Source: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ubuntu_(operating_system)#System_requirements