# Thinking of using ubuntu on an old laptop

Tags: installation

I am thinking of trying out ubuntu but have old Dell Inspiron 1501 amd turion 64 x2 1.6ghz 896 of ram but don't know what one to try. Please help?

Comment: possible duplicated [What are the system requirements for each flavor of Ubuntu Desktop?](http://askubuntu.com/q/333795/169736).

Answer (score 0):

I would take a look at [Lubuntu](http://www.lubuntu.net/) for a light weight distro.

Answer (score 0):

I own an old HP/Compaq with an amd turion 64x2 with 1GB of RAM.
Ubuntu 12.04 LTS runs not-too-fast but happily on it using Unity-2D. The regular Unity works also without any problems (thanks to the videochip, something you have to consider when choosing an Ubuntu version).

So yes, the standard ubuntu is definitely an option but if your videochip can't handle 3D you are stuck with Ubuntu 12.04 LTS (the last unity with 2D desktop support, and no LLVMpipe software rendering is NOT a realistic option on a Turion).
Ubuntu fits well in the "comfort zone" but it is definitely a bit of a resource hog.

However, I agree with Wouter. Lubuntu makes your computer fly again. :-)
It may be a bit spartan in some ways but it's beauty in elegance and simplicity.

(too far out of your comfort zone ? There is always Xubuntu, though I never liked it much)

Good advice: Whatever you choose, stay away from the newest versions. There are always some unresolved issues which may spoil your enthousiasm.