# which version for my netbook acer v5=121

Tags: acer, ubuntu-netbook

2gb RAM
500 gb HDD
AMD C- 70, 1 GHz
wireless, touch pad functions
which version is better

Answer (score 0):

I would install the 13.10 version of Ubuntu as it has the most features and is the most up-to-date. Because it is the most up to date it is the most likely to support all your hardware and have all the bugs worked out.

The best thing to do is to put Ubuntu on a USB drive (or DVD) and run it from the disk before you install it. That way you can do some testing to make sure that everything works for you.

The other option would be to go with the 12.04 release. This is the "Long Term Support" version and is a solid release but it does not have all the newest, cutting-edge features.

Here are the links to get either version:

http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop

Answer (score 0):

I recommend Ubuntu 13.10(*saucy salamander*)which was the latest version of Ubuntu.
See  [**this**](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/SaucySalamander/ReleaseNotes)  page for new features and minimum system requirements for ubuntu 13.10.

you can also pick the distro which satisfy your needs,from [`here`](https://askubuntu.com/questions/333795/what-are-the-system-requirements-for-each-flavor-of-ubuntu-desktop).