# Wich environment is faster than Unity?

Tags: unity, gnome, desktop-environments

I'm having a little trouble using my 305u samsung laptop with Ubuntu 13.10, it gets really slow.

Is there some environment like Gnome3 or other that can make it work faster than in unity?

Comment: They pretty much all are you can install the [Gnome Classic Desktop](http://askubuntu.com/q/58172/107450) or go for one of the other variants such as [Lubuntu](http://www.lubuntu.net/), [Xubuntu](http://xubuntu.org/getxubuntu/), [Kubuntu](http://www.kubuntu.org/getkubuntu/download) or [Ubuntu Gnome](http://ubuntugnome.org/) with the exception of Gnome Classic I would recommend a fresh install (once you have taken a backup) to get the cleanest system and they can all be tried form a live USB before you decide which you prefer and install it.

Comment: you should read [what are the system requirements for each flavor of Ubuntu Desktop?](http://askubuntu.com/q/333795/169736).

Answer (score 0):

Xfce4 is famous for being very lightweight, I don't know how it compares to Unity though. You could also try MATE (formerly GNOME 2) or LXDE. Window Maker is very lightweight and fast, but in my experience it takes a while to configure it to your needs.