# Graphic gibberish in a S3 Super Savage/IX

Tags: drivers, graphics, visual-artifacts

I installed Ubuntu 12.04 using the Windows installer on a Toshiba Tecra 9100 (vintage ~2002) with Windows XP Professional. When I boot to Ubuntu, the screen image is a mess indicating some sort of graphics problem. I tried to post a picture, but my reputation is not high enough.With the messed up graphics nothing is usable right from the start. The graphics processor is an AGP 4x - S3 Super Savage/IXC - 16MB.

Do you have any suggestions? Am I doomed to having a paperweight?

P.S. Computer has 512MB of memory

Comment: Have you tried other flavor? It happens when you use a LiveCD/USB?

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu 12.04 will not run on this machine: [What are the system requirements for each flavour of Ubuntu Desktop](https://askubuntu.com/questions/333795/what-are-the-system-requirements-for-each-flavor-of-ubuntu-desktop). Try Lubuntu. Even then, you should consider adding memory.

Comment: I have 512MB of memory

Comment: So Lubuntu will work but you must be careful with memory usage (processes in the background, number of browser tabs opened at the same time etc.)