# System Requirements For Installing Ubuntu

Tags: intel-graphics, system-installation

I wanted to know that can we install ubuntu on the following System Requirements:--

> Processor: Intel(R) Core(TM)2 Duo CPU     E4700  @ 2.60GHz (2 CPUs), ~2.6GHz
>                Memory: 2048MB RAM
>
> DirectX Version: DirectX 11

Display Devices

```
      Card name: Intel(R) G33/G31 Express Chipset Family
   Manufacturer: Intel Corporation
      Chip type: Intel(R) GMA 3100
       DAC type: Internal
     Device Key: Enum\PCI\VEN_8086&DEV_29C2&SUBSYS_75291462&REV_10
 Display Memory: 256 MB
```

Comment: Take a look a this post : [http://askubuntu.com/questions/333795/what-are-the-system-requirements-for-each-flavor-of-ubuntu-desktop](http://askubuntu.com/questions/333795/what-are-the-system-requirements-for-each-flavor-of-ubuntu-desktop) You will find system requirement for the latest ubuntu version.

Answer (score 0):

Without a semi-recent graphics card, Unity performance will probably suffer. [Xubuntu](http://xubuntu.org/getxubuntu/) and/or [Lubuntu](http://lubuntu.net/) will do just fine, though.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah with this configuration even if you install the OS successfully you may suffer from several hangings! My suggestion as well would be trying Light Ubuntu (Lubuntu) version.