# Will UBUNTU work smoothly with 1Gb ram and intel atom dual core processor?

Tags: system-installation

I want to use UBUNTU in my computer.

- ASUS EEE PC
- Intel Atom dual core processor
- 1GB RAM
- 360GB HDD

  Will it work without glitches and slow performance with this?

Comment: Smooth is a little subjective, and I personally would not run Ubuntu on this machine.  You might want to try something lighter like Lubuntu or Xubuntu.

Answer (score 2):

I have a Asus 1005 EEEpc, and since Unity as desktop enviroment it won't work fluid. Best performance I've achived is with Lubuntu (with LXCE) or using Linux Mint too. The problem is properly the desktop enviromenment you use.

Comment: I have the same PC. I have upgraded to 2G ram and now I am quite satisfied with the performances of Ubuntu Gnome Remix. I strongly recommend the RAM upgrade.

Answer (score 1):

- Yes,most of the Ubuntu flavours  will run smoothly on your pc which had 1 GB of RAM.
- It was better to try Ubuntu by booting Ubuntu live disk and then clicking on **Try Ubuntu** option on startup.
- To create Ubuntu live usb on windows see [this](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/create-a-usb-stick-on-windows) or in Ubuntu see [this](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/create-a-usb-stick-on-ubuntu).

Comment: Running vanilla Ubuntu on 1GB of RAM can be a real pain (I should know.) It tends to freeze all over the place, especially when running Firefox.

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't be so sure that default Ubuntu installation would run very well on 1GB of RAM.

I have done it on a Core Duo w. 1GB of RAM and it worked well for most of the time, but occasionally would freeze up entirely if I had too many programs open or tabs in Firefox, etc. So smoothly depends on what you want. If you want an entirely smooth system, default Ubuntu isn't the one you want.

Unity, the default Ubuntu Desktop Environment tends to be a bit heavy and slow on systems  like this. Atom processors are a very low end and combined with the 1GB of RAM your system would not be constantly smooth on your Netbook. There is an Ubuntu forums post here: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1869981 that looks like it fits your question perfectly.

You might want to look into [Lubuntu](http://lubuntu.net/) which you can get here: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Lubuntu/GetLubuntu

It runs on as little as 512MB of RAM and should be fine for your system.

How to create a bootable USB stick on Windows: http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/create-a-usb-stick-on-windows

and on Ubuntu/Linux:
http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/create-a-usb-stick-on-

and on OS X:
http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/create-a-usb-stick-on-mac-osx

This question may help: [What are the system requirements for each flavour of Ubuntu Desktop](https://askubuntu.com/questions/333795/what-are-the-system-requirements-for-each-flavor-of-ubuntu-desktop)