# Will Ubuntu 12.04 LTS run on my GIGABYTE GA-Z87M-D3H motherboard?

Tags: hardware

I'm looking to build a new computer and I want to use Ubuntu as my OS. I found [thi motherboard](http://www.gigabyte.com/products/product-page.aspx?pid=4486#ov) I am happy, with but when looking through the specifics of the board they state the following:

> "Due to different Linux support condition provided by chipset vendors,
>   please download Linux driver from chipset vendors' website or 3rd
>   party website."

So my questions is: Can anyone tell me if Ubuntu will work on this board?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What are the system requirements for each flavor of Ubuntu Desktop?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/333795/what-are-the-system-requirements-for-each-flavor-of-ubuntu-desktop)

Comment: @K7AAY your post link was helpful but it still didn't fully answer my question. Will it run? Is GIGABYTE trying to be helpful with their statement, or are they trying to cover themselves on the off chance another OS doesn't work?

Comment: it will install automatically, but you may need to reconfigure for best performance.

Answer (score 1):

The Scott Deagan and FangQ posts at https://communities.intel.com/thread/19133 indicate it will install automatically, but you may need to reconfigure for best performance. However, the CPU you select, since that generation of Intel CPUs also include the GPU, will determine the exact driver to select at http://www.intel.com/support/graphics/sb/cs-010512.htm

To enable SNA, you have to modify or create `/etc/X11/xorg.conf` to add the following:

```
Section "Device"
Identifier "Card0"
Driver "intel"
Option "AccelMethod" "sna"
EndSection
```

After doing this, reboot. You can check SNA is running by opening up a terminal and entering:

`grep -i sna /var/log/Xorg.0.log`

If there is output from the above command, then SNA is running.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to know is to try it on a live cd or usb key. If the live version works good, once installed, it will work better.