# How to install Ubuntu 13.10 on an old SONY computer?

Tags: installation, 13.10, system-installation

Hi, I am a noobie to Ubuntu, I have a Freelander Tablet that I want to develop APPS for. I have an old SONY MOD:PCV-RX270DS, Pentium III CPU, MEM: 256 MB.  I tried to PRE-install Ubuntu 13.10.  The computer Access the CD drv and starts to Install. It opens up with a purple screen to small Icons on bottom Middle then goes blank a blinking cursor in upper left corner and then runs forever.  All I see is the HDD activity light on the computer blinking on and off all the time. I let it run for 4 Hr. one time and it did nothing.

Comment: this is a various guide on all ways how to install Ubuntu https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation also I would advise to use something lighter according to your hardware specs take a look here https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/SystemRequirements and what partitioning scheme does Ubuntu use you can find over here https://help.ubuntu.com/community/DiskSpace

Answer (score 2):

Your system is not compatible with some current releases (no 64-bit version will work) of Ubuntu, and is not fast enough for the **recommended** [requirements](https://askubuntu.com/questions/333795/what-are-the-system-requirements-for-each-flavor-of-ubuntu-desktop).  Therefore, I recommend using the 32-bit (or 'x86') versions of [Xubuntu](http://www.xubuntu.org) or [Lubuntu](http://www.lubuntu.net) instead.

Comment: And another note, if the OP is worried about 32 bit ram limitations, I believe Ubuntu is PAE(Physical Address Extension) enabled by default which is what removes the ram limitations that is typically associated with 32 bit OSes(like Windows).

Comment: Academic since he only has 256MB of RAM.