# Can ubuntu server be installed on <1G hds?

Tags: server, 13.10, disk-usage

I just need to install a streaming server, but videos to be streamed are on a remote storage.

I just need the ubuntu server hd take as less space as possible to be portable (ubuntu server will be on a VM, so hd is just a file).

I read that the minimum is 1Gb but it still seems too big for my tastes and for what I have to do.

I was thinking about 512 Mb, it would be great...but will istall allow me to do so?
And even if I try some workaround the server will be ok?

If not, sorry if I ask here, what distro could do the job?

Comment: there is no Ubuntu server that is that little. Why can't 1 GB work if it's just a file?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What are the system requirements for each flavor of Ubuntu Desktop?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/333795/what-are-the-system-requirements-for-each-flavor-of-ubuntu-desktop)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ubuntu 12.04 LTS requires a minimum of 512MB of disk for base system (1GB with all tasks installed). (Source: https://help.ubuntu.com/12.04/serverguide/preparing-to-install.html

13.10 requires a 700MB minimum (https://help.ubuntu.com/13.10/serverguide/preparing-to-install.html)

So; I guess you will have to test it -perhaps on a virtual machine; to see what exactly you will need and whether it will fit or not.