# Partitioning an external hard drive for Linux

Tags: 13.04, partitioning, ssd, gparted

I want to partition an external SSD hard drive (30GB) for Ubuntu. What is the proper size for main partition, Swap partition and for the rest? I want to use remaining disk space to store files, so this also should have proper filesystem. How to make this with GParted?

Comment: Everybody uses different numbers for such things. In general I use 20 Gb minimum for /root and no more then 1 Gb for swap. However, you can use more or less then 20 Gb for root and there are sometimes valid reasons to either not use swap at all or increase swap size. See http://askubuntu.com/questions/333795/what-are-the-system-requirements-for-each-flavor-of-ubuntu-desktop

Answer (score 1):

Also for your questions on how to do this with gparted, the manual might help.
http://gparted.org/display-doc.php?name=help-manual

Comment: In general we try to avoid answering questions with a link (because over time such things can go 404 or become outdated). Try to copy the essential information to answer the question and use the link "for additional information". IMO use the official ubuntu documentation wherever possible before 3rd parties (because the Ubuntu documentation is more likely to be accurate for ubuntu).