# Ubuntu requirements

Tags: 14.04

A notebook Sony Vaio with the following requirements

- CPU Intel Core 2 Duo T5500 1.66GHz
- Memory 2GB DDR2 SDRAM (533MHz)
- HDD 320GB
- Screen 15.4" WXGA (1280x800)
- Graphics NVIDIA GeForce Go 7400 (suporting 256MB)

supports Ubuntu 14.04 LTS?

Answer (score 0):

The system requirements vary among Ubuntu products. For the main Ubuntu desktop product, the official Ubuntu Documentation recommends a 1 GHz Pentium 4 processor with 1 GB of RAM[44] and 5.9 gigabytes of hard drive space, or better.[45] For less powerful computers, there are other Ubuntu distributions such as Lubuntu and Xubuntu.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ubuntu_%28operating_system%29#System_requirements

i would say go for it! good luck and have fun

Answer (score -1):

To run Ubuntu Unity the requirements are:

- 1 GHz processor (for example Intel Celeron or better)
- 1 GB RAM (system memory)
- 5 GB of free hard drive space for installation
- 3D Acceleration Capable Videocard with at least 256 MB

According to your spec, your laptop can run Ubuntu.

Source: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/SystemRequirements

Comment: My graphics card has 256MB shared, will be enough?

Comment: It should be ok, the strict req is on OpenGL 1.4 and your card supports 2.0 (http://www.nvidia.com/object/go_7_series_techspecs.html)

Comment: @SylvainPineau Your source should be in [this answer](http://askubuntu.com/a/333796/147044) which is updated to the current date.

Comment: @RaduRădeanu: ok, let's close it as a duplicate. thanks