# Can I install ubuntu 14.04 32-bit on an older desktop with 1gb RAM?

Tags: system-installation

When I attempt the install, my mouse freezes as soon as I select the install option.  I can get through the process using the keyboard, but, the system hangs at "Configuring boot loader...".  Any suggestions?

Thanks,
H

Comment: try ubuntu 12.04, if you are satisfied with your install, upgrade after locking your kernel version.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What are the system requirements for each flavour of Ubuntu Desktop](http://askubuntu.com/q/333795) or [How do I find out which version and derivative of Ubuntu is right for my hardware in terms of minimal system requirements?](http://askubuntu.com/q/206407). This is being interpreted as a question about minimum specs and has an answer about that. So you may want to ask a new question on the "Configuring boot loader..." problem. Or if you prefer, [edit] this, including its title. (I'm not sure which is better, in part as I don't know what info you're really looking for.)

Comment: Semi-duplicate; OP is asking about as specific distro *version*, which may (or may not) have changes in requirements.

Answer (score 0):

[Xubuntu 14.04.1](http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/xubuntu/releases/14.04/release/) LTS 64bit is fast and works like a charm with only 1GB RAM memory installed. As for the 32bit version of Xubuntu 14.04.1, you should have no problems with that one.

For a fancy desktop and look, you can install KDE Plasma Desktop, after you're done with installing Xubuntu, and also finished peforming all required upgrades. Plasma Desktop is a lite and very cool alternative to the Unity desktop. And you'll be able to boot into both the XFCE session and also the KDE session (plasma desktop session).

Answer (score 0):

Try  Official  derivatives [Xubuntu](http://xubuntu.org/)  or [Lubuntu](http://lubuntu.net/) these are good for Light system Having  **(RAM<=1GB)**

Keep Swap Approx: **1 GB** while installing

the swap partition would help Better Performance