# Ubuntu hardware requirements and best version

Tags: dual-boot, upgrade, hardware

- Processor Intel Celeron D
- RAM 780 mb
- Hard disk 500gb updated sata
- Lg cd/DVD writer

I don't know software programming. Can install a CD, so I need simple instructions.

Comment: Your question is not clear... but if you're looking for hardware  requirements, it looks like your computer will pass. The 'best version' question is difficult to answer (Ubuntu versions are not like Windows versions), but my advice would be to get the latest LTS release (in this case the latest release, 14.04 Trusty Tahr).

Comment: I'm not sure what you are asking here but you can find the hardware requirements for the main *buntu flavours [here](http://askubuntu.com/q/333795/107450).  You can create a boot able DVD or USB for any of them.  I'd suggest you try Xubuntu and Lubuntu without installing initially. Play with them both then install the one you prefer.

Answer (score 0):

The main branch of Ubuntu will run in the hardware you have listed.
However it will feel rather slow.

My suggestion is to run Lubuntu or Xubuntu, these two variants of Ubuntu requires less resources, and you'll have a better experience.

**Detailed info:**

The main branch of Ubuntu 14.04 by default comes with **Unity** user interface (optionally you can get it with the **Gnome** user interface), both of these will work in your old machine, but it will feel very slow, not recommended.

Xubuntu 14.04 is the same as Ubuntu, but running **XFCE** user interface (like WinXP), it's less fancy looking than Unity, but it does the job well, still very customizable, Xubuntu is a good medium ground between fancy Ubuntu and dry Lubuntu, it should run smooth enough on that old hardware.

Lubuntu 14.04 uses the **LXDE** user interface (like Win95) is even leaner and lighter than Xubuntu, it works well even on 486 machines, so if Xubuntu feel slow for you, you can try Lubuntu.

I usually salvage old machines to donate them for people that needs it, and I put Xubuntu on Pentium 2 to early generation of Pentium 4 machines, Lubuntu on 486 and Pentium 1 machines, any AMD/Intel machine built after Pentium 4 generation tends to runs well on the main branch of Ubuntu.

Make sure to get the i386 version of the CD ISO instead of the AMD64.