# How long for a stable installation for Ubuntu 14.04?

Tags: 14.04, updates, stable-release-updates

I know that when a new release is published it means that is  tested for a long time, but during the first weeks it happened to discover some bugs, and going on the bugs are decreasing.

I installed 14.04 on my notebook just yesterday and I will make some tests on and I know I will solve any problems with internet help.

I would like to install Ubuntu on old relatives pcs, but I would like to give them pcs where they can have fun with no problem (or very few ones)...

With a lot of amazement I discover that a lot of user suggest to install Ubuntu 12.04 that seems more stable than the lastest version. I think it is not a stupid idea, but I do not need to pass to Ubuntu quickly, so I prefer to wait for the new version (14.04).

The question is: when it will be the right moment for Ubuntu 14.04?

Comment: Ubuntu 14.04 is now stable, it has had the first point release (14.04.1).

Comment: I've installed 14.04.1 a few days ago and I must say it`s surprisingly stable. Previously I had 12.10 and I did experience quite the number of crashes on it, but since I got 14.04 I don't recall seeing one crash. Also you must consider the fact that if you install an older version, the packages available via the repository will not be as up to date as with the latest LTS, and that for me is a no-brainer

Comment: I have no problem with hardware to install Ubuntu 14.04, the time decision it is about discovered bugs

Answer (score 11):

**Ubuntu 14.04** is officially released on 17 April 2014. Which is **LTS(Long Term Support)**.

For Question:

> How long for a stable installation for Ubuntu 14.04?

Ubuntu 14.04 LTS will be supported for **5 years** for Ubuntu Desktop, Ubuntu Server, Ubuntu Core, Kubuntu, Edubuntu, and Ubuntu Kylin.

From https://wiki.ubuntu.com/LTS:

> A new LTS version is released every 2 years. In previous releases, a
>   Long Term Support (LTS) version had 3 years support on Ubuntu
>   (Desktop) and 5 years on Ubuntu Server. Starting with Ubuntu 12.04
>   LTS, both versions will receive 5 years support. There is no extra fee
>   for the LTS version; we make our very best work available to everyone
>   on the same free terms. Upgrades to new versions of Ubuntu are and
>   always will be free of charge.

[image]

> ### Furthermore, we define the LTS to be:
>
> - Enterprise Focused: We are targeting server and multiple desktop installations, where the average user is moderately risk averse.
> - Compatible with New Hardware: We will make point releases throughout the development cycle to provide functional support for new server and
>     desktop hardware.
> - **More Tested:** We will shorten the development window and extend the Beta cycle to allow for more testing and bug fixing

Alos visit [**Release Notes**](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/TrustyTahr/ReleaseNotes).

If you are talking about **system-requirements**, then visit: [What are the system requirements for each flavour of Ubuntu Desktop](https://askubuntu.com/q/333795/256099)

Answer (score 6):

The right moment for 14.04 is now - it has been updated to point release recently. I would suggest to use only LTS releases of Ubuntu, and install them right after point update release.

Answer (score 4):

Ubuntu 14.04 was released in April of this year, should be stable, and currently receives the most up-to-date software. If there are bugs they will be fixed. Ubuntu 14.04 is supported until April 2019.

Ubuntu 12.04 was first released in April 2012, and has since been receiving updates. It could be thought of as more stable as it has been around for longer and most bugs should be fixed, though it might not get as up-to-date software. It is supported until April 2017.

You can find the currently supported releases [here](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Releases), it also had releases notes for each release and point releases (e.g. [12.04.4](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/PrecisePangolin/ReleaseNotes/ChangeSummary/12.04.4), [14.04.1](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/TrustyTahr/ReleaseNotes/ChangeSummary/14.04.1)). If you are concerned about minimum hardware requirements, 14.04 and 12.04 should have mostly similar requirements - [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/333795/what-are-the-system-requirements-for-each-flavor-of-ubuntu-desktop) covers this in more detail.

Answer (score 2):

As your friends suggested 12.04 is pretty much bug free as of now. The same cannot be said for 14.04. There are bugs that go back as far as April. So we can only wait and see how long it takes. (Scroll through some of the unanswered questions and try to tell me alot of them are not bugs for 14.04)

As far as hardware support is concerned, 14.04 is the better choice.

---

The problems and bugs that need to be worked out don't seem to be issues you will find yourself dealing with months or even weeks from now. From what I've experienced, if there are bugs that effect your specific hardware, you will know very soon after installation. Most of the 14.04 problems I've dealt with were encountered during setup, installation, and initial configuration of the OS along with applying the first fresh set of software updates.