# can i run Ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS 64 bit in my computer?

Tags: 14.04, 64-bit, intel

**my computer specification**

Processor => intel core 2 duo E7300 @ 2.66Ghz

RAM => 3GB DDR2 800MHz

Graphics => AMD radeon HD 5570 1GB DDR3

Hard Drive => 500GB

*please tell me can i run the Ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS 64 bit in my computer.
thanks in advance.*

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Ubuntu 14.04 LTS 64 bit will run on your computer. The specific system requirements are as follows:

## **Minimum**

- 384 MB of RAM
- 700 MHz processor (about Intel Celeron or better)
- 5 GB of hard-drive space
- VGA capable of 1024x768 screen resolution
- Either a CD/DVD drive or a USB port for the installer media

## **Recommended**

- 1 GB of RAM
- Dual Core processor
- 10 GB of hard-drive space or SSD (the more hard disk capacity, the better)
- Any graphics card with OpenGL 1.4 support (All GPUs released today by either NVidia, AMD or Intel; GPUs released by NVidia and AMD over the last 5 years; GPUs released by Intel after the GMA 950)
- Either a CD/DVD drive or a USB port for the installer media
- Internet access is helpful

(Information taken from [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/333795/what-are-the-system-requirements-for-each-type-of-ubuntu-desktop))