# Duration Process

Tags: 14.04

Hey Guys I would like to ask if how long does it take to install the Ubuntu 14.04 recommended setting and the minimum requirements the exact time duration. thanks >.<

Comment: possible duplicate of [What are the system requirements for each flavour of Ubuntu Desktop](http://askubuntu.com/questions/333795/what-are-the-system-requirements-for-each-flavour-of-ubuntu-desktop)

Answer (score 2):

This is something you can't say, as it depends on a multitude of factors such as the hardware it is installed on, the media used and many more.

Comment: And internet connection for updated packages, how fast you can type your username and passwords, select keyboard layout and partition your drive. :) But I usually take about 20-30 minutes from start to finish. About an hour to completely update and install software aswell.