# Ubuntu on a ThinkPad A30

Tags: system-installation, thinkpad

I just installed the latest version of Ubuntu on my old ThinkPad A30.  It's running SUPER slow.  I have 1GB RAM, a 30GB HDD, and the system has a Pentium III processor running at 1GHz.  I thought that would allow it to run at a normal speed, but no.  It might take 5 seconds to acknowledge that I've typed a single letter!

Any suggestions on a solution?  Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What are the system requirements for each flavour of Ubuntu Desktop](http://askubuntu.com/questions/333795/what-are-the-system-requirements-for-each-flavour-of-ubuntu-desktop)

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu requires a lot of resources these days. 1 GB of RAM is nearly not enough anymore to run stock Ubuntu.

Your options could be to:

- Install another variant of Ubuntu like Xubuntu.
- Remove Unity from your Ubuntu and install a light weight Desktop Environment like Openbox
- Install another distro that is light weigh.
- Try to tweak down Unity. You could install CompizConfig from Ubuntu Software Center and disable all the fancy desktop effects.