# Ubuntu GNOME 14.04.1 LTS Minimum Requirements

Tags: gnome, 32-bit

Is it possible to install Ubuntu GNOME 14.04.1 LTS (32 bit) on My System

- 1 GB of RAM
- AMD Athlon 64 processor (32bit)
- 100 GB of hard-drive space

What are the Minimum Requirements For Ubuntu GNOME 14.04.1 LTS

Comment: possible duplicate of [What are the system requirements for each flavour of Ubuntu Desktop](http://askubuntu.com/questions/333795/what-are-the-system-requirements-for-each-flavour-of-ubuntu-desktop)

Comment: It is possible, although you may find a lighterweight desktop environment to give you better performance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the [Ubuntu GNOME Wiki](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/TrustyTahr/ReleaseNotes/UbuntuGNOME), the minimum requirements are:

> - 1 GHz processor (for example Intel Celeron or better)
> - 1.5 GB RAM (system memory)
> - 7 GB of free hard drive space for installation

So, it doesn't sound like your computer will have enough RAM to run Ubuntu GNOME.  The processor and hard-drive space seem to be sufficient, so I suppose you could just get more RAM and see if it works, but you may have better luck anyways running Xubuntu or Lubuntu.