# Disk Space required for installation of Ubuntu

Tags: 14.04

What is the maximum disk space required for the complete installation of Ubuntu 14.04 ?

And what are the minimum system requirements for butter smooth working of the OS ?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think the installer will want to start unless there's a minimum of 5 or maybe 6GB of space available. I don't believe there is a maximum.

Minimum requirements for "butter smooth" I don't know, but the regular min requirements are here https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/SystemRequirements

700 MHz processor (about Intel Celeron or better)
512 MiB RAM (system memory)
5 GB of hard-drive space (or USB stick, memory card or external drive but see LiveCD for an alternative approach)
VGA capable of 1024x768 screen resolution
Either a CD/DVD drive or a USB port for the installer media
Internet access is helpful

And the link muru mentioned has great info on the other Ubuntu's too: [What are the system requirements for each flavour of Ubuntu Desktop](https://askubuntu.com/questions/333795/what-are-the-system-requirements-for-each-flavour-of-ubuntu-desktop)