# How to install ubuntu

Tags: dual-boot

I'm Thu and i'm from Viet Nam.This is my problem:
My computer was setup dual the Windows 7 and Windows 8.1
So how can i install ubuntu in my computer.
Thank!

Comment: was the computer pre-installed windows8 or windows7?

Comment: What is the actual problem with installing Ubuntu? Please be precise and [edit] your question accordingly. There is no problem with one or more versions of Windows being installed. Possible duplicate: http://askubuntu.com/q/6328/40581

Answer (score 0):

download Ubuntu, write it to a disk or a usb
create some unallocated space to install Ubuntu,i hope you know how to as you already installed two Operating systems 
boot to Ubuntu live disk or usb and click install

it is same as dual boot
you can find detailed instructions [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WindowsDualBoot)

Answer (score 0):

Actually you can achieve it three ways...

whichever the way you find easier and comfortable give your damn shot to that.

First of all you need to have ISO file of the version of Ubuntu which you would like to install.
Got to: [Download Ubuntu Desktop](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop)

For which version you should go for:

**1.** [How do I find out which version and derivative of Ubuntu is right for my hardware in terms of minimal system requirements?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/206407/how-do-i-find-out-which-version-and-derivative-of-ubuntu-is-right-for-my-hardwar)

**2.** [What are the system requirements for each flavour of Ubuntu Desktop](https://askubuntu.com/questions/333795/what-are-the-system-requirements-for-each-flavour-of-ubuntu-desktop)

**1. Install [VmWare](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VMware) and Run Ubuntu on it.**

Complete Instruction you will find on following link: [How to Install VMware and Use VMware to Install Ubuntu](http://www.wikihow.com/Install-VMware-and-Use-VMware-to-Install-Ubuntu).

**2. Install with help of [WUBI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wubi_%28software%29)**

Complete Instruction you will find on following link: [Wubi Guide](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/WubiGuide)

**3. Install Ubuntu on separate Partition.**

1) In order to do this you will need boot-able Flash Drive. So got to: [How to create a boot-able USB stick on Windows](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/create-a-usb-stick-on-windows).

2) To install it on separate partition, [Windows Dual Boot](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WindowsDualBoot).

Comment: I'd suggest to do not ruin Win Boot-loader setup and use it with WUBI setup. But first check that either Win & boot-loader is in use or Win 8. A you are rookie. First get comfortable with Ubuntu and GRUB and that go for complete setup.

Answer (score 0):

download the latest image of the ubuntu.and write it in a DVD.insert the dvd in your computer's drive.then restart your system keeping the DVD inside the drive.the boot loader automatically load the Ubuntu. it will give you the option that install the Ubuntu along side the windows. click that option.after finishing the setup the Ubuntu will be dual booted with windows