# How to increase speed of ubuntu 14.10 32bit?

Tags: 14.10

My system configuration is 1GB RAM,Pentium 4 processor,I installed ubuntu 14.10 in my system recently.The operating system was too slow, and it is reacting very slower. So,I want to increase my systems speed, tell me what changes I should do to increase it's speed.

Answer (score 2):

That will not be possible. It will be slow whatever: [the 'recommended' requirements](https://askubuntu.com/questions/333795/what-are-the-system-requirements-for-each-flavour-of-ubuntu-desktop) state a dual core with 1Gb.

I would suggest installing another version of Ubuntu: [lUbuntu](https://askubuntu.com/a/333861/15811) or xUbuntu. Those are lightweight and will get you a better experience.

- [lUbuntu](http://lubuntu.net/) can be found here and uses the [LXDE](https://www.google.nl/search?q=lxde&client=ubuntu&espv=2&biw=1551&bih=815&tbm=isch&tbo=u&source=univ&sa=X&ei=FYTpVKr9K8TaOImVgZAF&ved=0CC4QsAQ&dpr=1) desktop
- [xUbuntu](http://xubuntu.org/) can be found here and uses the [XFCE](https://www.google.nl/search?q=lxde&client=ubuntu&espv=2&biw=1551&bih=815&tbm=isch&tbo=u&source=univ&sa=X&ei=FYTpVKr9K8TaOImVgZAF&ved=0CC4QsAQ&dpr=1#tbm=isch&q=xfce) desktop