# Problem in installing Ubuntu

Tags: boot

I have downloaded Ubuntu 14.4, my laptop is 32-bit 512 MB RAM, and followed the way guided for installing Ubuntu 14 by using USB  bootable making by universal USB installer, but it not get installed, the boot shows following message.

```
SYSLINUX 4.07 EDD 2013-07-25 COPYRIGHT (c) 1994-2014 H. Peter Anvin et al. ERROR: No configuration file found: no DEFAULT OR UI configuration directive found.
```

Please help in installation.

Comment: Can you [verify the integrity](//help.ubuntu.com/community/HowToMD5SUM) of the files on the USB drive?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What are the system requirements for each flavour of Ubuntu Desktop](http://askubuntu.com/questions/333795/what-are-the-system-requirements-for-each-flavour-of-ubuntu-desktop)

Comment: You'd be better off with Lubuntu!  (See link above)

Answer (score 0):

See if you can hash-check the ISO you downloaded against the [hash provided on the site](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UbuntuHashes).

If the hash checks out, you may have accidentally downloaded the wrong build or your computer might not have sufficient memory to run the liveCD.

Comment: Your answer is based on mere assumptions.

Comment: just checked it and found it is same

Comment: @A.B. agree. This should be a comment not an answer.