# Total newbee, Mac, is 222GB too much space in partition?

Tags: partitioning, virtualization

Can a partition on a Mac HD be too large for VM Ubuntu?  I partitioned 222GB when I first got my Mac Mini ; it has a T hard drive.

Comment: Is large, but not too large.  I think that is a reasonable amount.

Answer (score 1):

Most computers operating systems, even in Virtual Systems, are not very limited in how big a hard drive space they can manage. The only limit is perhaps the [filesystem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_system) used - so for example, if `ext4` is used , the maximium sensible limit [is 16 tebibytes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ext4) (roughly 1099 GB, 1024 GiB)

So as long as you have a space for Ubuntu [of at least 10 GiB](https://askubuntu.com/a/333796/178596), it should be fine for most uses. I generally use a minimum of at least 50 GiB for the root system on installations I do (with at least 40 GiB for the home and up to 8 GiB swap space) - having a larger space available is not a problem and is usually a benefit, though you will want to leave some free space available for the Mac system.