# novice Ubuntu-user: beginners assistance

Tags: dell, ssd

Hello possible fellow Ubuntu-users,

Until now I've been using Windows operating systems and my current laptop is going to retire soon. In my search of a new, basic (read: not too expensive) laptop I thought about Ubuntu several times. As a computer enthousiast I have a basic knowledge and interest but this is far from the expert-level. Recently I was pleased to see a big computer brand to launch a budget model including a pre-installed Ubuntu Linux 14.04 SP1 operating system with the following specs:

*Processor: Intel® Celeron® Processor N2840 (1M Cache, up to 2.58 GHz) 
Operating System: Ubuntu Linux 14.04 SP1 
Memory: 4GB Single Channel DDR3L 1600MHz (4GBx1) 
Hard Drive: 500GB 5400 rpm Hard Drive 
Video Card: Intel® HD Graphic 
Display: 15.6-inch HD (1366 x 768) Truelife LED-Backlit Display 
Wireless: 802.11bgn + Bluetooth 4.0, 2.4 GHz, 1x1*

The laptop will be used for the basis stuff: internet, documents,...
Does this configuration seem adequate to run Ubuntu smoothly?

I'm also considering to change the 5OOGB HDD with a 250 SSD drive for some faster handling.
Having read some basis research it should be possible. However I'm doubting if I will succeed to transfer the pre installed files to the new SSD drive and run Ubuntu. Any experiences for a Ubuntu novice are highly appreciated.

Hopefully you guys or girls can guide this windows-user into a new and bright Ubuntu age :-)

thx alot!

grtz

Comment: Computer is good for Ubuntu.

Comment: This is more to be off-topic as it's a hardware recommendation like *what do I need to buy*? If you'd like to know common hardware requirements to run Ubuntu than it can be a duplicate to [this](http://askubuntu.com/questions/333795/what-are-the-system-requirements-for-each-flavour-of-ubuntu-desktop) or [this](http://askubuntu.com/questions/206407/how-do-i-find-out-which-version-and-derivative-of-ubuntu-is-right-for-my-hardwar) topic.

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu (as any other Linux distribution (Linux is the kernel, a distribution provides a working environment based mostly on other open source applications)) would work well on this PC, especially when you add the SSD. But of course "good performance" is always a little bit subjective, so just try it out. To make things easy start a new installation of Ubuntu on the new SSD, you can then copy any important files via a 2.5" harddisk USB adapter. When you have transfered your files use this HDD for backup.

For web browsing you can install chrome or firefox via the Ubuntu Software Center. For email you can use thunderbird. Linux and Open Source is about freedom so choose the applications that suit your needs at best.

If you discover issues with your hardware you can open a command line (= terminal or console) and you'll get hardware information via the commands lshw, lspci, lsusb. You can then google for help on driver settings or similar.