# Which version of Ubuntu should I use for my old compaq laptop?

Tags: 14.04

my PC is a Compaq evo N210c 
my processer is intel pentium 3
im just trying to bring this old pc back to life could i put ubuntu 14.04?

Comment: How much RAM is installed there?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What are the system requirements for each flavour of Ubuntu Desktop](http://askubuntu.com/questions/333795/what-are-the-system-requirements-for-each-flavour-of-ubuntu-desktop)

Comment: I would start with 12.04, then if OK update to 13.04. Then if OK update to 14.04. There are some other related issue  such as CPU and graphics system that may cause problems. If 14.04 is OK keep it, otherwise go back and reinstall the latest that works.

Answer (score 0):

If you are holding 2GB RAM means you can go for Ubuntu 14.04 LTS 32Bit.

But my Suggestion is to leave at-least 1 GB or 2Gb of Space for SWAP.