# Will Ubuntu Run?

Tags: configuration, system, system-requirements, preinstallation

I would like to know if ubuntu 15.04 will run on my Asus Laptop. Below is the configuration

- 1.33GHz Intel Atom
- 2GB Ram
- 7.5 GB Harddisk Space(With Windows 8.1 already installed)
- Intel HD Graphics

At the some time I would not like to remove my Windows 8.1.

Comment: Hardware related questions are off topic. Ubuntu is free so you can just download it and try it out. See http://askubuntu.com/questions/333795/what-are-the-system-requirements-for-each-flavour-of-ubuntu-desktop  Then again: you expect Ubuntu to use MORE resources than Windows 8? If W8 runs smoothly so will Ubuntu.

Comment: @Rinzwind the thing is that I wanna Dual Partition it. So do think it will soomthly ?

Comment: 7.5GB hard disk ? partitioning that space between two operating systems will not work smoothly. You will soon run into problems.

Comment: @RatnakarPawar I was wondering whether I could Install ubuntu 15.04 on an SD Card and boot from it.. I Mean the OS and all the files I create in ubuntu should remain in the SD Card Itself... Is this possible ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the specs you specified it would be more than possible to install ubuntu by shrinking the windows 8 partition;

the minimum requirements for ubuntu are as follows;

700 MHz processor (about Intel Celeron or better)
512 MiB RAM (system memory)
5 GB of hard-drive space (or USB stick, memory card or external drive but see LiveCD for an alternative approach)
VGA capable of 1024x768 screen resolution
Either a CD/DVD drive or a USB port for the installer media
Internet access is helpful

i think the only issue would be available space AFTER ubuntu is installed.