# Obtaining better performance?

Tags: performance

i'm a Lubuntu 14.04 user. I have some trouble about my CPU going to a high % usage while doing simple things like launching firefox.

I would some advice if there is some fixing that I can do to improve my system performance.
Maybe should change to another light flavour like xubuntu?

My general use is personal office.

### Especifications:

- Processor     : Intel(R) Core(TM)2 Quad CPU    Q6600  @ 2.40GHz
- Memory        : 2045MB (1290MB used)
- Operating System      : Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS
- -SCSI Disks-

  - ATA WDC WD3200AAJS-0
  - ASUS DRW-2014L1T

Comment: No need for anything unrelated to -speed-.

Comment: Here is the min.req list: http://askubuntu.com/questions/333795/what-are-the-system-requirements-for-each-flavour-of-ubuntu-desktop There is not much difference between xUbuntu and lUbuntu (they gave similar specs).

Answer (score 0):

You want better responsiveness? Add RAM. Changing DE (Ubuntu flavour) will not give you much good.
Firefox itself is very resource hungry and you can't do much about it, unless you disable some major functionality. Both big browsers are getting bigger and bigger with every release. May be switch it for something lighter?