# If, Ubuntu 16.04 LTS is suitable Asus Eee Pc with 1GB RAM

Tags: 14.04, asus, 16.04

I am using 14.04 LTS on Asus Eee pc which has intel atom N455 and 1GB RAM. The 14.04 runs normally on my asus. My question is if my processor and RAM is suitable for updation 14.04 LTS to 16.04 LTS. Also if may any error comes after the updation especially packages like apache,cinnamon and war of wesnoth etc

Comment: Lubuntu or Xubuntu are a better choice for such PCs rather than original Ubuntu.

Comment: If, Xubuntu and Lubuntu looks like a original Ubuntu

Comment: Or you can try Ubuntu Mate 16.04 the 32bit version. The 64 bit version requires more ram.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What are the system requirements for each flavour of Ubuntu Desktop](http://askubuntu.com/questions/333795/what-are-the-system-requirements-for-each-flavour-of-ubuntu-desktop)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I find out which version and derivative of Ubuntu is right for my hardware in terms of minimal system requirements?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/206407/how-do-i-find-out-which-version-and-derivative-of-ubuntu-is-right-for-my-hardwar)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [download page](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop) of Ubuntu, it will not perform really well with RAM under 2GB. There are other Ubuntu flavors out there that may suit your system [here](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/UbuntuFlavors)

Comment: If this answered your question, please tick the green checkmark on the left of this answer. This will mark it as solved.

Answer (score 1):

I recently installed Ubuntu 16.04 on a 701 with 1GB RAM. I used the mini iso installer, added Xfce, PostgreSQL, Midori, emacs, git-all, musescore, abiword, swi-prolog, a few other things.

I tend to remove /usr/share/docs/* and /var/apt/cache/archives/* as I go since I either already know what the tools I need do, or I have docs on another system, and I don't need to keep the debs around either. So, with the above installed, as well as some working space used in my home dir, I have 782MB left still.

I am running the PostgreSQL server continuously. I am running a Catalyst server alongside that, being served by it (doing some development work). I can run Midori, several instances of the terminal, emacs, and other tools running in multiple tabs without ever having got to the point of it feeling sluggish.

I did swap out the 1GB RAM for 2GB just so I knew I could have some extra headroom if I started to do anything really intense, but the above runs fine in 1GB.

I've even driven my 27" monitor at 1440x900 just fine as well as an extra screen, again with no appreciable lag or sluggishness.

I am not running overclocked either. Just standard clock speed.

All is well - for me at least. YMMV, but I have no concerns about performance with 16.04 on the 701.

I'm not running any login manager, just logging in and running startx

[Here's my desktop](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S1jO8.png)

Hope that helps. :-)

Answer (score 0):

I have Lubuntu 16.04 running on a Medion Akoya E1210 (an MSI Wind clone). This is an Atom N270, which is a very similar in performance terms when compared to your N455, albeit the N270 is 32-bit and GPU-less. With 2GB of RAM, it's acceptable for casual use, although rendering web pages can be slow (e.g. when JavaScript kicks in). I wouldn't try LibreOffice on it for the same reasons.

However, the OS itself is perfectly acceptable for navigation, window management, file management, and similar.

Lubuntu and the lightweight 'buntu derivatives will run any application that runs on full-fat Ubuntu, but you may find that you have to install e.g. additional Gnome libraries for some things.

Answer (score 0):

Recommended RAM is 2GB...so I would suggest you stick to Ubuntu 14.04 LTS for optimum performance...IMHO and from experience...for 32bit machines with 1GB RAM, Ubuntu 12.04 runs the smoothest...so if you don't have any particular needs...do not upgrade...

Comment: I would recommend Lubuntu or Xubuntu 16.04. Up to date and lightweight and fast.