# Can I install the latest version of Ubuntu

Tags: upgrade

Processor: Intel(R) Pentium(R) M processor 1.70GHz 1.70GHz

32 bit operating system

36.3 free of 55.7 GB

Windows 7 HP Home Edition

HP pavallon dv1000.                    ( can i get the latest Ubuntu? )

Comment: Is this on topic?

Comment: You can create a Ubuntu bootable USB and try it before you install it. If it works properly, it will be fine to install the latest version of Ubuntu. http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/try-ubuntu-before-you-install

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can run the latest version of Ubuntu. I have a similar laptop with a Pentium M, and Ubuntu MATE runs fine.

*However*, you should definitely use one of the lightweight variants of Ubuntu, such as [Ubuntu MATE](http://ubuntu-mate.org/) or [Lubuntu](http://lubuntu.net), as your laptop may not be able to run the standard Ubuntu with Unity adequately.

The system requirements for Ubuntu can be found [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/333795/what-are-the-system-requirements-for-each-flavour-of-ubuntu-desktop).

Comment: Do they have terminal and which one is better for my computer

Comment: @ShadowHoverCat Yes, all versions of Ubuntu have a terminal. What you choose is up to you - Lubuntu may be faster, Ubuntu MATE has more features. There's also other versions of Ubuntu, e.g Xubuntu and other distros as well.

Comment: how fast would my computer run then?

Comment: @ShadowHoverCat I have a computer with a Pentium M and it runs Ubuntu MATE just fine. To make web browsing feel fast, I use Firefox (not Chrome) and use the uBlock Origin Firefox add-on to block ads. (Some people also use the NoScript or FlashBlock addons.) I also have to use the 32-bit version of Ubuntu MATE, since the 64-bit version doesn't work properly with my processor. If you have very little RAM, Lubuntu would be a better choice than Ubuntu MATE.

Answer (score 1):

No problem.  Like @JonasCz said, good idea to try MATE or LXDE or XFCE.  If you want a smoother feel, try LXDE with `cairo-dock`.  It works well on similar specs for me.

Comment: I wouldn't recommend Gnome - it's quite resource hungry and needs lots of memory and CPU resources to run well. It isn't really suitable for a Pentium M with <1GB RAM.