# What Linux system would be best for my laptop?

Tags: windows

Can I use Xubuntu 4.12 on a Intel  Celeron B800 processer on a laptop computer, the 14.4 Trusty Tahr or what Linux Os will work on a Aspire Laptop with a Intel Dual core B800 Processor with 1.5Ghz 2GB DDR3 memory 500 GB HDD

Comment: Please use http://askubuntu.com/questions/333795/what-are-the-system-requirements-for-each-flavour-of-ubuntu-desktop as a reference

Comment: Please, reformulate your question so that we can clearly know what PC configurations you got and the distros you have in mind for them. As it is right now, your question is quite unclear.

Comment: Take a look at http://askubuntu.com/questions/206407/how-do-i-find-out-which-version-and-derivative-of-ubuntu-is-right-for-my-hardwar

Answer (score 1):

If you are still monitoring this thread, Lubuntu 16.04 will probably be your best bet with those specifications.

Comment: I will go with Lubuntu or Ubuntu Mate.

Comment: Both of those are incredibly light on system resources and should be a good fit.

Comment: That sounds good to me I will do it