# ubuntu for LX800 processor

Tags: 14.04

**nonpae**
Is it possible to install an updated version of Ubuntu onto an **LX800** processor?
The computer has 1G of Ram 8G flash disk. For a number of years I've been using these computers (PC104) as IOT type devices using Ubuntu 8.04 and Ubuntu 10.04.
Thank you

Comment: This answers your questions https://help.ubuntu.com/community/PAE

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What are the system requirements for each flavour of Ubuntu Desktop](http://askubuntu.com/questions/333795/what-are-the-system-requirements-for-each-flavour-of-ubuntu-desktop)

Answer (score 0):

Wikipedia: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geode_(processor)

The LX 800 states that it has 500Mhz. A Ubuntu desktop needs 700Mhz to run.

Use Ubuntu Server or another distrio instead.

(*It pays to use LiveCD's!*)

Comment: What is with the random comment with (light) profanity? Might want to remove that before someone gets offended and flags it :)

Comment: So what version of Ubuntu server to install and how?

Comment: @SteveS The latest LTS release. the installer functions just like Ubuntu Desktop. But if you are not intending to build a server, use either Ubuntu MATE or Lubuntu. (use google to get download ISO's)

Comment: @MarkKirby I doubt that will not happen..