# Will this PC spec support Ubuntu?

Tags: drivers, nvidia, asus, intel, compatibility

A bit of a tedious one, hopefully it's okay to ask this here...

I was hoping someone could help me figure out if this PC build will work with Ubuntu? I've had trouble installing Ubuntu on my laptop in the past and now am finally biting the bullet and buying a new desktop. I'd like to set up a duel boot Windows 7 / Ubuntu and hardware really isn't my area (software man). I will be using this PC mostly for various development projects including openGL 3D graphics stuff so I'd like to be sure that my graphics card is compatible with Ubuntu as well!

If anyone could tell me if my plans will work out and offer any advice you have in general I'd be very appreciative! I've tried looking through the compatibility databases but I don't have much confidence in myself when it comes to hardware! None of this spec is set in stone, feel free to suggest changes and if I'm in the wrong place please point me in the right direction :)

**Processor**
Intel® Core™i5 Quad Core Processor i5-6600K (3.5GHz) 6MB Cache

**Motherboard**
ASUS® Z170-E: ATX, LG1151, USB 3.1, SATA 6GBs

**Memory (RAM)**
16GB HyperX FURY DDR4 2133MHz (2 x 8GB)

**Graphics Card**
2GB NVIDIA GEFORCE GTX 960 - DVI, HDMI, 3 x DP (Special!!)

**1st Hard Disk**
2TB SATA-III 3.5" HDD, 6GB/s, 7200RPM, 64MB CACHE

**1st DVD/BLU-RAY Drive**
24x DUAL LAYER DVD WRITER ±R/±RW/RAM

**Power Supply**
CORSAIR 450W VS SERIES™ VS-450 POWER SUPPLY

**Sound Card**
ONBOARD 6 CHANNEL (5.1) HIGH DEF AUDIO (AS STANDARD)

**Wireless/Wired Networking**
10/100/1000 GIGABIT LAN PORT (Wi-Fi NOT INCLUDED)

**USB Options**
MIN. 2 x USB 3.0 & 2 x USB 2.0 PORTS @ BACK PANEL + MIN. 2 FRONT PORTS

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/333795/what-are-the-system-requirements-for-each-flavour-of-ubuntu-desktop is the topic to look at.

Comment: Your hardware is definitely powerful enough to run any Ubuntu flavour you want. About compatibility issues with any component, the best is to try it out in a live session before installing. Simply create the installation DVD/USB, boot from it and select "Try Ubuntu without installing" to play with it a bit and see whether all your devices operate properly. Note that it will be slow (especially if you use a DVD) because of the slow boot device in live mode.

Comment: U have everything awesome... yeah sure..it will work

Comment: overkill, bro... you can run Ubuntu on hardware several times slower than that you have listed.

Comment: @patrick You can run Ubuntu on a raspberry pi!