# Compatibility with Ubuntu

Tags: windows

Let me preface by saying I`m not a computer geek but I am SO VERY tired of windows systems and ALL the non-stop glitches they are plagued by.
Well the latest windows torture device I purchased is a Lenovo Ideapad 100S, question is; Is this device compatible with a version of Ubuntu?

Comment: Yes, Ubuntu will work with an Atom CPU. As that is a low power laptop, I would point you to https://xubuntu.org/ or http://lubuntu.net/ for better performance.

Comment: We do not provide hardware recommendations ;)  See http://askubuntu.com/questions/333795/what-are-the-system-requirements-for-each-flavour-of-ubuntu-desktop for a general idea on what operating system fits

Comment: Just try a live USB. That way you'll know if it works or not before you install. Also, +1 for @MarkKirby's suggestion of xubuntu or lubuntu instead of plain ubuntu

Comment: @MarkKirby Just FYI, the *official* site for Lubuntu is http://lubuntu.me

Comment: I would also recommend Xubuntu, well any distro using the xfce desktop actually. I use xfce excusively even on high end machines.

Comment: It looks like that was one of the systems orginally designed to not allow Linux. It uses a 32 bit UEFI. When designed Linux did not have 32 bit UEFI. You need to download the 32 bit UEFI files separately and use them to boot. LENOVO Ideapad 100S Laptop  32 bit UEFI bootia32.efi
https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2350606