# What type of Ubuntu can be installed on my netbook?

Tags: ubuntu-netbook, compatibility

What type of Ubuntu can be installed on my old netbook?

Spec

Benq Joybook u105i

•   Intel Atom N450 processor

•   1GB of RAM

•   Chipset  : Intel NM10 Express Chipset,

•   Graphics : Intel GMA3150

Comment: Ubuntu-Mate, Xubuntu, Lubunt, all should work relatively well. Just don't expect too much.

Comment: I would replace the 1GB ram memory with 2GB and would give a try with elementary loki os 64 bit. I've checked it on my N145 netbook and runs better than ubuntu with unity.

Comment: Lubuntu works OK on my netbook with a N270, so you might be happy with that.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What are the system requirements for each flavour of Ubuntu Desktop](http://askubuntu.com/questions/333795/what-are-the-system-requirements-for-each-flavour-of-ubuntu-desktop)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Lubuntu](http://lubuntu.me/) would be a nice start.