# HP Compaq nx 6325 slow performance on Ubuntu 16.10

Tags: 16.10, hp, compaq

I have followed a number of bug reports on various platforms, all reporting similar problems and which have acknowledeged this as a bug - however, as a relative newbie to linux I am battling to understand the to and fro jargon associated with this bug regarding kernel patches etc, but have been unable to find a definitive fix.

I know thic is an old laptop, but I would like to pass it on to an as a working machine to an aspiring student. Windows 10 does run OK on this platform (certainly a wee bit more responsive and quicker than Ubuntu 16.10 which I didn't expect).

Is there a fix for this bug - and more importantly - simple easy to follow instructions to apply the fix ?

Your help would be much appreciated

Comment: Try Lubuntu. (Lubuntu is Ubuntu with a lightweight GUI instead of the resource-hogging Unity) The difference will be night and day.

Comment: Related: http://askubuntu.com/questions/333795/what-are-the-system-requirements-for-each-flavour-of-ubuntu-desktop

Comment: I tried Lubuntu first, but had the same problem

Comment: This bug was also reported across Lubuntu and Kubuntu

Comment: The closest related bug I could find was https://bugzilla.kernel.org/show_bug.cgi?id=189291 - I just couldn't follow if there was a resolution