# Ubuntu on low end pc

Tags: compatibility

Do ubuntu 16 will work on my laptop which has

4gb ram
64 bit processr
2 gb intel and nvidia graphics

I think that it won t' work on 4gb ram

Comment: See [What are the system requirements for each flavour of Ubuntu Desktop](https://askubuntu.com/questions/333795/what-are-the-system-requirements-for-each-flavour-of-ubuntu-desktop)

Comment: I would suggest Xubuntu instead of regular Ubuntu

Comment: Have a look at the following link and links from it, 'Try Ubuntu (Kubuntu, Lubuntu, Xubuntu, ...) before installing it', https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2230389

Answer (score 2):

Yes it will. I have it running on my 12-year-old Dell laptop which is maxed out on 4GB RAM and it works nicely.

I strongly suggest replacement of the disk with an SSD, though. It decreases startup time to a few seconds and everything goes faster. If you do this, add noatime,discard options to your fstab mount. Plenty of resources out there for migration to SSD but a new install is amazingly easy.

Keep the system monitor open and with 4GB it will need swap space.

Mike