# System requirements for Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, system-installation

I've an Intel Celeron N3060 processor with 2 GB RAM and 32 GB of internal storage. Can I install Ubuntu 16.04 on this laptop?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu. Please have a look [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/SystemRequirements) or use Google the next time ;) further depends on what you are going to install and run. Look on the according software provider's page

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/333795/what-are-the-system-requirements-for-each-flavour-of-ubuntu-desktop

Comment: lubuntu or xubuntu should work fine. lubuntu is the lighter one

Answer (score 0):

The simple answer is: *Yes*

The more complicated answer is: *It depends*

While Ubuntu 16.04 *will* install and run on that system, you are going to be potentially running into issues when your 32 GB storage fills up ***(and if you are not careful, that can happen quite quickly)***.

Also, I am guessing that the 32 GB is one of those eMMC drives which do not take too friendly to lots of changes (they are basically an SDCard on a stick.) If you are not planning on installing much software, and are very mindful, you will do fine.

For a beginning user, you might frustrate yourself with those specs *(the storage in particular).*

Hope that helps!