# Is there anybody runnig a Linux distro on Dell Latitude E5570?

Tags: drivers, dell, hardware, compatibility, distro-recommendation

I am considering to switch from Win to Linux. However, due to my previous experience sometimes it just does not work as expected. I bought Latitude E5570 (128 Gb SSD, intel i5, 8Gb RAM) with Win 7 preinstalled. Which Linux distro is the most compatible one with this Laptop configuration?

Comment: We have a generic answer for these kind of questions: https://askubuntu.com/questions/333795/what-are-the-system-requirements-for-each-flavour-of-ubuntu-desktop General idea: Ubuntu is free. Try each of the versions out and make  your own opinion about what you like.

Answer (score 0):

i have been using ububtu 17.04 on a dell 5420, which is a slightly older model then yours. but i have no to few compatibility issues. 
i must say that i am not a heavy user (no gaming or audio via laptop or any other special demands) so some incompatibilities might not have been noticed.

none the less i must add that i find ubuntu is definately the best linux distro available and there is an amazing support here on this forum.

must warn you though, if not familiar with linux. for some parts there is a steap learning curve (personally i'm still in there) but for normal daily use.. it's ready to go. and for the other parts there is this forum.  but once you go linux you never go back. I never linked windows.. but now i really dislike it.

personally i hate it that i have to have a special windows laptop for those programs that are only supported on windows, (which i usually only need because external hardware linked)

i'd say.. start with a dual boot system (not as difficult as it sound, the install guide will get you through) with prefered boot to ubuntu. Once you feel more comfortable. remove windows..

enjoy!